# Create 2 matrices based on list of index value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a scipy sparse matrix - `title` - and a python list `index`. The list contains integers which correspond to rows in the `title` matrix. From this I wish to create 2 new scipy sparse matrices:

- One should contain all of the rows in `title` except if the index number is in `index`
- The other matrix should contain all of the rows in `title` which index numbers are in `index`

Eg.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
titles = sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((5,5)))
index = [3,2]
```

Where the desired output for `print(matrix1.todense())` is:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

and the desired output for `print(matrix2.todense())` is:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

Comment: Which has nothing to do with pandas. Also, how about a [mcve]?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.setdiff1d` to find exclusive indices and just index `titles` appropriately.

```
idx1 = [3, 2]
idx2 = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(titles.shape[0]), idx1)

matrix1 = titles[idx2].todense()
matrix2 = titles[idx1].todense()

print(matrix1)
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]

print(matrix2)
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```